# "This file can't be previewed because of an error in the Microsoft Word previewer."

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, attachments, preview

The issue is:
Outlook 2013 simply will not give a preview of Word (nor Excel) docs in attachments.

Never had the issue with Outlook 2010. Using Outlook 2013 on Windows 7 64bit SSD with Word 2010.

I did notice that "Microsoft Word" is not listed specifically in Trust Center attachment handling, could that be part of the problem?
Excel, Visio, RTF and many more are there.

Update: strange, search can be performed in Word attachments... but can't preview Word file. So, Outlook can 'see' Word docs but won't let us have that preview.

For reference, [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/this-file-cant-be-previewed-because-of-an-error-in/67925c80-c05b-4536-90ed-2a1aa3011b50) is a similar question I posted in the Microsoft Answers forum.

Comment: Try running outlook as admin (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/this-file-cant-be-previewed-because-of-an-error-in/5ead8652-a71c-4a7f-a271-487f59c3003a)

Comment: Linking to an existing forum where the problem was discussed is not acceptable here because links can die. For the purpose of improvement, please [edit] your question to include the basic idea of the information included in your link so the post is still relevant if the link dies.

Comment: On another note; do I understand correctly you have only upgraded Outlook but not all Office applications to 2013? Has this issue happened the entire time with Outlook 2013? Or did it work previously (besides with 2010)? Have you tried a repair install of Outlook 2013?

Answer (score 7):

1. Close outlook → Start Regedit
2. Navigate to `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PreviewHandlers`

*Make sure to back up the contents of course*

3. Delete the key for *Microsoft Word previewer*
4. Restart outlook → preview a Word doc & you should now get a
   message “ *You should only preview files from a trustworthy source*
   ”

Comment: This solution fixed the problem for TXT previewer as well (with Outlook 2010). However it appears to have BROKEN the txt previewer in Windows Explorer. (Oh, well. I rely on the Outlook previewer much more often.)

Comment: Also, this did not fix the problem for PDF previewer. (In that case I got a new message: "This file cannot be previewed because there is no previewer installed for it.") And it broke the Windows Explorer pdf previewer. A re-install of Adobe fixed Explorer's previewer, but not Outlook's.

Comment: I used this to fix the TXT previewer in outlook. I didn't actually delete the key, I just renamed it to `{1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22} OLD` so it was backed up in place

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the temp file folder exceeds its storage level.

just do the following & the problem is solved.

1. Exit outlook if its running
2. Go to "START" & find the "Run" function
3. In "Run" Function type or paste the following:

   %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.Outlook\
4. A Folder will be open & there is a sub folder. Open the Sub folder & Delete the entire files, contain in the sub-folder.
5. Please don't delete the sub-folder.

& done.

Open the Outlook & it will working properly

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just a work-around and doesn't feel like a legitimate solution, but it worked for me.

Thanks to [this link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2011/11/30/excel-open-corrupt-files/). In short:

1. Open the application (Word, Excel, etc.)
2. Click on File -> Options
3. Select Trust Center
4. Select Trust Center settings button.
5. Select Protected View.
6. Uncheck "Enable Protected View for Outlook Attachments" (or all the options under Protected View) and confirm by pressing OK.
7. Restart the application and try to open the "broken documents" from Outlook.

Comment: It doesn't work.